# Epoch date constantly returning the same value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using the moment.js library for date formatting, but am unable to return any value other than the Unix Epoch start date. The following code iterates through the Transport for London data for buses, pulling out the Epoch timestamp for each bus that is coming:

```
var epoch = key[i].toString().split(",").slice(3,4).toString().replace('"', '');
epoch = epoch/1000;

var day = moment(epoch);
```

This is a working example, if you check the console:

http://tfl.applied-espi.com/bus-popup/

Comment: Please create a self-contained example. Like give us an actual value for `epoch` in the example above. Also, if you have *additional* code to share, then please share it in a way that is future proof, like on http://jsfiddle.net I doubt your http://tfl.applied-espi.com/bus-popup/ will still be available for future visitors. (It doesn't even run for me right now, some `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'countdown' of undefined`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just don't do it `epoch = epoch/1000;`

and don't forget to convert string to integer

`var day = moment(parseInt(epoch));`

Comment: It says 'invalid date' when I do that.